# Running Qt Unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt4

Looking at [Qt's site](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=qt+unit+test&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), and at [another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524390/qt-what-unit-testing-framework/3804999#3804999) because I don't want to create a separate project for each class I want to test, I've come up with the following code:

testqstring.h

```
#ifndef TESTQSTRING_H
#define TESTQSTRING_H

#include <QtTest/QTest>

class TestQString : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void toUpper();
};

#endif // TESTQSTRING_H
```

testqstring.cpp

```
#include "testqstring.h"
#include <QString>

void TestQString::toUpper()
{
    QString str = "Hello";
    QCOMPARE(str.toUpper(), QString("HELLO"));
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "testqstring.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestQString testqstring;
    QTest::qExec(&testqstring, argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I receive the following linker errors:

```
...
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -arch i386 -o tester main.o testqstring.o moc_testqstring.o -F/Library/Frameworks -L/Library/Frameworks -framework QtCore 
Undefined symbols: 
"QTest::qExec(QObject*, int, char**)", referenced from: 
_main in main.o 
"QTest::compare_helper(bool, char const*, char*, char*, char const*, char const*, char const*, int)", referenced from: 
bool QTest::qCompare<QString>(QString const&, QString const&, char const*, char const*, char const*, int)in testqstring.o 
... and more like that ...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't you need to link with QTest?

Comment: @Noah what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add:

```
CONFIG += qtestlib
```

to the .pro file to get qmake to link in the qtest library.

Comment: Or nowadays: "QT += testlib"