# How do you testrun your c++/Qt programs/projects with template classes? (Automated unit testing in 2020)

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I was confronted with a Think-Cell development position test in which a big part - if not the most important part - was testing the final version of the program one has written that contained a template class. So lots of testing is possible.

In my experience from open source projects the bare minimum is tested to make the program run&done and solve bugs by "creative users" that do stuff programmers wouldn't ever come up with.

In the books I red and I learned from was just some minimal input IO handling for int/char/strings but nothing explicitly about testing the program with all/the most possible use cases.

But I really like the idea of writing a test program that covers all events/possible use cases especially a commercial use case and I can Imagine writing one general testing library that fires all kinds of data on the program that covers as much as possible would be handy wouldn't it?

And yes, I already googled and found some [unit testing posts from '08 '10](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unit%20testing%20c%2B%2B) also [qt unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524390/what-unit-testing-framework-should-i-use-for-qt)
or ['04](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle) and after that [google test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16FI1-d2P4E) seem to dominate the market but even there one has to come up with all the different test cases that really takes time f.e in case of template classes.
Also the Qt toolkit already has a [Qt unit testing library](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html)

***So my question is: How do you / What do you use or do to test your projects/programs in 2020? Do I have to write/come up with my own testing methods/classes redundant for every program/project every time new?
Isn't there already a way to automate the testing in a way errors/warnings are showing up f.e. in the qt creator during the programming process?***

Comment: I use the testing framework that is part of `CMake` since all of my projects are using CMake anyways.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for your fast answer, I just googled it and found an article about TDD https://bastian.rieck.me/blog/posts/2017/simple_unit_tests/ that really is a way to think about "to write the unit tests before you write your actual code"